# while select with join firstOnly

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

Is there any chance i could join two tables like this ?

```
while select  SalesId from salesTable
    //group by SalesId
    where salesTable.SalesId == "xxx006932683"
    join firstOnly SalesPrice, ItemId, LineNum from salesLine
    //group by SalesId
    order by salesLine.LineDisc asc, salesLine.SalesPrice desc 
    where salesLine.SalesId == salesTable.SalesId
{
    info(strFmt("Sales id : %1 line %2 item %3 price %4", salesLine.SalesId, salesLine.LineNum, salesLine.ItemId, salesLine.SalesPrice));
}
```

So, for each line in `SalesTable`, join it with the only one line in `SalesLine` with the same `SalesId` and satisfying the order condition.

To be honest, i have tried a lot of groupings and orderings and maxOfs, minOfs with no success... so here i am asking for an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to admit this is the most strangest query I have written so far :

```
SalesQuotationTable salesQuotationTable;
SalesQuotationLine  salesQuotationLine;

CustQuotationSalesLink    custQuotationSalesLink;
CustQuotationJour         custQuotationJour;
;  

while select maxof(QuotationId), maxof(CurrencyCode) from salesQuotationTable
    group by QuotationId, CurrencyCode, RecId
         where salesQuotationTable.QuotationStatus    == SalesQuotationStatus::Sent
            && salesQuotationTable.QuotationType      == QuotationType::Sales
          //&& salesQuotationTable.QuotationId        == '00015683_042' just for testing

join maxof(lineNum), minof(lineAmount), maxof(QuotationId) from salesQuotationLine
    group by lineNum, lineAmount, QuotationId, RecId
         where salesQuotationLine.QuotationId         == salesQuotationTable.QuotationId
            && salesQuotationLine.QuotationStatus     == SalesQuotationStatus::Sent
            && salesQuotationLine.QuotationType       == QuotationType::Sales
            && salesQuotationLine.SalesQty            > 0

//duplicate values were coming from here, grouping was the way to go
join maxof(QuotationDate), maxof(QuotationId) from custQuotationSalesLink
    group by OrigQuotationId
         where custQuotationSalesLink.OrigQuotationId == salesQuotationTable.QuotationId

join maxof(QuotationDate) from custQuotationJour
         order by custQuotationJour.QuotationId
             where custQuotationJour.QuotationId      == custQuotationSalesLink.QuotationId
                && custQuotationJour.QuotationDate    == custQuotationSalesLink.QuotationDate
```

A few notes:

**1**. Instead of

```
select firstonly custQuotationSalesLink
     order by QuotationDate desc, QuotationId desc
        where custQuotationSalesLink.OrigQuotationId == this.QuotationId
```

I have used

```
join maxof(QuotationDate), maxof(QuotationId) from custQuotationSalesLink
     group by OrigQuotationId
         where custQuotationSalesLink.OrigQuotationId == salesQuotationTable.QuotationId
```

The party starts here, from what i have seen, once using a group by, all the fields from the other tables seem to be empty. So the solution is to **add group by everywhere.**

You see i am adding the RecId into groupings to be sure i am not really grouping anything :)

In order to get fields with values you have to add an aggregate function in the select clause. Ok , cool, why not, as long as i am not grouping for real.

**2**. But the catch for me was at the last part:

```
join maxof(QuotationDate) from custQuotationJour
    order by custQuotationJour.QuotationId
          where custQuotationJour.QuotationId == custQuotationSalesLink.QuotationId
                 && custQuotationJour.QuotationDate == custQuotationSalesLink.QuotationDate
```

That **order by** did the trick. I don t know why. If i switch it with a **group by** which seems normal to me, i get duplicated values. So all the groupings added before are just losing their relevance. I guess sometimes a bit of luck has to join the game too. I mean, why thinking at **order by** there. Maybe because it s Wednesday, i don t know.

I had to use some aggregation on the last join because otherwise i wouldn t have got a value for the `QuotationDate` field which in fact is the whole goal of this work.

**This link helped me a lot :**

http://axatluegisdorf.blogspot.ca/2010/07/select-group-by-and-join-order-by.html

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that in one select statement. 
First you can create a view on sales line with grouping on SalesId and maxOf, minOf, ... on fields you need. 
This view should return only one record for each SalesId. Than you can join this view to sales table.

If you only want to get first line of order then you have to do nested selects.
Best way is to create a temp table with fields you need and fill it with data.

```
while select SalesId from salesTable
{
   select firstOnly SalesPrice, ItemId, LineNum from salesLine
      order by salesLine.LineDisc asc, salesLine.SalesPrice desc 
      where salesLine.SalesId == salesTable.SalesId
   ;

   //insert into temp table

   info(strFmt("Sales id : %1 line %2 item %3 price %4", salesLine.SalesId, salesLine.LineNum, salesLine.ItemId, salesLine.SalesPrice));
}
```

But in your case (because you have where statement on SalesId <- unique) this will work fine

```
select firstOnly SalesPrice, ItemId, LineNum from salesLine
   order by salesLine.LineDisc asc, salesLine.SalesPrice desc 
   where salesLine.SalesId == "xxx006932683";
```

Comment: How can you ensure the ordering by `LineDisc` and `SalesPrice` and include the `SalesPrice`, `ItemId` and `LineNum` in the field list using this approach?